# Loading selected Hibernate entities with JPA & Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, jpa

Is there a way to load only selected entities with Hibernate?

I would like to only load a selected handful for integration testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a custom persistence.xml and gave it to the EntityManagerFactory in the spring config.

Answer (score 2):

I create an [`AnnotationConfiguration`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html) programatically for this kind of tests and use methods such as [`addAnnotatedClass(Class)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html#addAnnotatedClass(java.lang.Class)) to "enlist" entities.